# Pass values between views in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I have 2 views and need to pass values between them.

```
var appModel1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: '/',
        defaults: {
            name: 'Default name'
        },
        validate: function(attr){

        }
    });

    var appCollection1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: appModel1
    });

    var collection1 = new appCollection1();

    var model1 = new appModel1();
    model1.bind('change', function(){
        model1.save();
    });


    var appView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: model1,
        _modelDataBind: undefined,
        el:'#container1',
        initialize: function(){
            this._modelDataBind = new Backbone.ModelBinder();
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template($('#app1').html());
            this.$el.html(template);
            var bindings = {
                    name: '#txtName'
            };
            var changeTrigger = {
                    'changeTriggers': {
                        '': 'keyup',
                        '#txtName': 'keyup'
                    }
            };
            this._modelDataBind.bind(this.model, this.$el, bindings, changeTrigger);
        },
        'events': {
            'click #btnSubmit': 'addRecord'
        },
        addRecord: function(){
            collection1.push(model1);
            var item = '<li>Name: ' +  model1.get('name') + '</li>';
            var app2 = new appView2({collection: collection1});
            $('#txtName').val('').focus();
        }
    });
    var view1 = new appView1({});


    var appView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#container2',
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template($('#app2').html());
            this.$el.html(template);
            this.collection.each(function(model){
                var item = '<li>Name: ' + model.get('name') + '</li>';
                $('#infoList').append(item);
            });
        }
    });
    var view2 = new appView2({});
```

As of now, I have only been able to pass values using collection and id variables.

Are they reserved variables?

Can i use any other variable to pass data?

```
var app2 = new appView2({nameObj: nameObj});
```

this fails.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as the first **Related** question in the sidebar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per docs, Backbone view only acts upon `model, collection, el, id, className, tagName, attributes and events` properties of options object.

However, you can pass any other data you want, the whole `options` object will be available as the first parameter of `initialize` callback.

For example:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#container2',
  initialize: function(options){
   // access your data here
    this.valuableInformation = options.valuableInformation;
    if(!options.doNotRender)
      this.render();
  },
  render: function(){
  }
});

new AppView({
  valuableInformation:"it's nothing",
  doNotRender: true
});
```

Comment: the parameter sent to the view is basically a json, you will have to wrap the variable names in quotes as those are strings and are not predefined keywords like model or collection. So your example will look like `new AppView({ "valuableInformation": "it's nothing", "doNotRender" : true})`;

Comment: @SandeepSukhija It's a javascript object, no need to quote anything unless the property name isn't a valid javascript variable name.